# Firebase Js How do store an array of values into each row in their respective key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an input field where the user is able to write new input or make changes to their previously added input.

I am able to retrieve the inputs by using .map but I am stuck afterwards as I am not sure how to store the values.

```
var pickUp = $("input[name='pickUp[]']")
          .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

For example using p1,p2 ... as the key:

The inputs

[image: Input Field]

The results I want (the database values below are manually added in):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both bankaujjwal and Ashiq Muhammed makes sense. But to use their method I would have to change the way I set my input field.

So I tried the another way which it works too.

Im not sure if its the right way to do it. But since it has solved my problem, I will use this as the answer.

```
var pNo= 1;
for (var i = 0; i <pickUp.length ; i++) {
var key = "p";
key+=pNo;

firebase.database().ref(uid + '/pickUp').update({

[key]: pickUp[i]  

});

pNo++
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reference link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

```
let the dynamic values that you want to update are stored in a object 
const data = {
 p1: 'area1',
 p2: 'area2',
 p3: 'area3',
 and so on....
}

const valueRef = firebase.database().ref('/Location_to _data/pickUp');
  for (var key in data) {
   if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    valueRef.update({
     [key]: data[key]
    });
   }
  }
```

.update({}) Will update the data if it exist or make a new one if its not there.
This will solve your problem.

Comment: But if the user decided to add in more inputs it will have p5 , p6,p7 and so on. There will also cases where there will be less than 4 records. So I didnt use the method you shown as it has fixed values.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly. you can just map over the data that you want to update.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by giving a common class name for all the inputs to form an object. Also give all the input tags a corresponding ID

Let's say the class name be  :

```
<input id='p1' class='objectClass' />
<input id='p2' class='objectClass' />
<input id='p3' class='objectClass' />
<input id='p4' class='objectClass' />
.
.
.
```

Now in javascript use :

```
var i = 1;
var obj = {};
$('. objectClass').each(function(){
  var key = "p" + $(this).attr('id');
  obj[key] = $(this).val();
  i++;
});
```

Now the obj will have the data stored in the format of your choice. Now all that is left is just to store it in firebase database :

```
firebase.database().ref('/path_to_location/').set(obj);
```